# How to define a scalar placeholder with known shape in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to define a scalar placeholder like:

```
alpha = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(),name='alpha')
```

The problem is that its shape is `<unknown>`:

```
print(alpha.get_shape())
<unknown>
```

When `alpha` is multiplied by another tensor, its output shape is also `<unknown>`:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,128,128,3],name='x')
I = alpha * x
print(I.get_shape())
<unknown>
```

This creates a problem since `I` is feed into a convolution operation which uses `fan_in = k_h * k_w * input_.get_shape().as_list()[-1]` where `input_` is `I`. As a result following error pops up:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

I'm looking for a neat way to solve this problem. Preferably, defining a scalar placeholder with a known shape.

Comment: `alpha.get_shape()` works for me. What's your tf version?

Comment: @Maxim It is  "1.2.1"

Comment: @Maxim Interesting in "1.0.0" it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use tf.shape(input)[0] for representing the None shape of the placeholder.